# write a function to extract an element from a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, how to extract the seventh element of a list without using the prelude functions length or (!!).

The following is what I have so far:

```
element7 :: [a] -> Int -> a
element7 [] _     = error "list too short"
element7 (_:xs) 7 = element7 xs (k - 1)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: You basically reimplement the prelude function (!!). That seems to be the goal of this exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright let's start with what we have

```
element :: [a] -> Int -> a
element [] _     = error "list too short"
element (_:xs) 7 = element7 xs (k - 1)
```

Now that last case is when we're at 7, but we're really interested in any number greater than 0

```
element (x:xs) n | n > 0 = element xs (n-1)
```

then if `n` is 1, we just return the head

```
element (x:xs) n | n > 0 = element xs (n-1)
                 | n == 0= x
                 | otherwise = error "Index out of range"
```

Now we just have to create a nice shortcut for finding the 7th element:

```
seventh xs = element xs 6
```

Comment: So instead of using `!!` you chose to reimplement the function and call it `element` (and use 1-based indexing). ;-)

Comment: I'm just leaving this here due to the "no prelude functions" constraint. And I'm switching it to 0 based because it's bugging me a bit

Comment: The OP wrote `without using the prelude functions length or (!!)` which to me sounds as if using Prelude functions is okay, except for `length` and `!!`.

Comment: Indeed, it also is meant to follow from the OP's starting code. Though I wouldn't ever use something like this in my code, I'll happily leave it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
seventh (one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:rest) = seven
```

Comment: I'd use `_` to denote values you're not interested in, i.e. `seventh (_:_:_:_:_:_:x:_) = x`, and also consider adding `seventh _ = error "List is too short"`.

Comment: I'm being a bit facetious, though I nearly made `safeSeventh :: [a] -> Maybe a`.

Comment: using fully named arguments is more pedagogical and self-documentary.

Comment: And `-Wall` will yell at me for having unused variables. Truly the best way is to write it as `safeSeventh` with `(_one:_two:_three:_four:_five:_six:seven:_rest)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version which drops the first six letters of the given string and then returns the first letter of the remainder:

```
seventh = head . drop 6
```

Comment: The question says you cannot use prelude functions. head and drop are from prelude

Comment: @Ankur: I read `without using the prelude functions length or (!!)` as   "You can use prelude functions except `length` or `!!`".

Comment: Hmmm... seems like a type ambiguity in English type system ;)

Comment: @Ankur: Well the OP used [`error`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Err.html#error) which is in the Prelude, too - so I understood that it's indeed okay to use.

Answer (score 0):

This solution try to be closer to your attempt:

```
element :: [a] -> Int -> a
element []     _ = error "list too short"
element (x:_)  1 = x
element (_:xs) i = element xs (k - 1)
```